# Convert User ID to Name with AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to populate the name of the contact owner ('referred to as the retention owner in our organization) in an email subject line in Marketing Cloud using AMP Script.

Based on the code below, I am able to bring over the ID but am wanting to convert the ID to the individual's name. Below is what I have so far.

```
%%[
  VAR @retentionOwner
  SET @retentionOwner = AttributeValue("Retention_Owner__c")
]%%
%%=v(@retentionOwner)=%%
```

May I have advice and guidance on what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a look at [How to Format my Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), specifically the code block. Proper formatting will increase the likelihood of other people answering your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to lookup the name in the synchronised data extension with all the users:

```
%%[ 
VAR @retentionOwner 
SET @retentionOwner = AttributeValue("Retention_Owner__c") 
SET @ownerName = Lookup(User_Salesforce,”Name”,”Id”, @retentionOwner)
]%% 
%%=v(@ownerName)=%%
```

If you are working in a child business unit, you must reference the data extension with ENT in front: ENT. User_Salesforce

Comment: Thanks Lukas! That solved my problem. Thank you for your help!